# UI hover effect working in Unity Editor but not in game build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a card game. When I hover over one of my cards using PointerHandlers, it finds the images of the card in question and changes their colors as appropriate. This works great in the Unity Editor. However, in the actual game build, the highlighting no longer works. All other UI elements are working fine.

Is there an easy way to debug this from the game build itself? Or else, does anyone have any immediate items that would be worth checking? The cards shown here are created via a prefab and are thrown into a Scroll View.

Edits:
Platform is Windows Desktop.

Code of the script changing colors successfully in the Editor, it's attached to the "FindDeckManager" object via the prefab:

```
public class CardHover : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
public Image[] cardImages;

public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log(eventData.pointerEnter.name); //this always read as "FindDeckManager" as expected when entering the cards
    if (Draggable.hoverDisabled == false)
    {
        // moved this to Start --- cardImages = gameObject.transform.parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();

        foreach (Image thisImage in cardImages)

        {
            if (thisImage.sprite.ToString() != "null" && !thisImage.color.ToString().Contains("0.502"))
            {
                thisImage.color = new Vector4(255f / 255f, 255f / 255f, 0f / 255f, 255f / 255f);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (Draggable.hoverDisabled == false && cardImages != null)
    {
        foreach (Image thisImage in cardImages)

        {
            if ((thisImage.ToString() == "Image (UnityEngine.UI.Image)" || thisImage.ToString() == "Frame (UnityEngine.UI.Image)")
                && !thisImage.color.ToString().Contains("0.502"))
            {
                thisImage.color = new Vector4(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
            }
        }
    }

}
 }
```

[image: Example of the hover effect working in the editor]

**Update:** the foreach loop is causing the issue. If I remove it and just reference the cardImage[#] themselves, it works fine. I tried using a for loop with i = 0, but still no luck. It's almost like cardImage is recognized as being a 0 length array in a for/foreach loop even though it's not (and that's confirmed since I can set each value outside of the for/foreach loop).

**Update 2:** Bizarre... if I don't use a for or foreach loop and just look to the specific image in question, it works fine. Any ideas why this is? It doesn't make any sense to me.

```
 public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (Draggable.hoverDisabled == false)
    {

        if (cardImages[1].sprite.ToString() != "null" && !cardImages[1].color.ToString().Contains("0.502"))
        {
            cardImages[1].color = new Vector4(255f / 255f, 255f / 255f, 0f / 255f, 255f / 255f);
            cardImages[2].color = new Vector4(255f / 255f, 255f / 255f, 0f / 255f, 255f / 255f);
        }
    }
     }
```

**Update 3:** I wouldn't call this an answer, but a workaround without having to use GameObject.Find or something similar is to store off the images in question on Start and then just reference them from then on out.

```
public Image[] cardImages;
public Image imageResult;
public Image frameResult;

public void Start()
{
    cardImages = gameObject.transform.parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();
    imageResult = Array.Find(cardImages, element => element.name == "Image" && !element.color.ToString().Contains("0.502"));
    frameResult = Array.Find(cardImages, element => element.name == "Frame" && !element.color.ToString().Contains("0.502"));
}

public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (Draggable.hoverDisabled == false)
    {

        if (imageResult != null && frameResult != null)
        {
            imageResult.color = new Vector4(255f / 255f, 255f / 255f, 0f / 255f, 255f / 255f);
            frameResult.color = new Vector4(255f / 255f, 255f / 255f, 0f / 255f, 255f / 255f);
        }
    }
}

public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (Draggable.hoverDisabled == false)// && cardImages != null)
    {

        if (imageResult != null && frameResult != null)
        {
            imageResult.color = new Vector4(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
            frameResult.color = new Vector4(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Platform - mobile, desktop? Code of UI element?

Comment: Desktop. The code is pretty simple but I can add it - a pointer enter and pointer exit method. Pointer enter is what matters here and when the mouse enters the object, it finds the parent (the card itself) and then looks back down to find all the images within the children. The Frame and Image objects have image components which is finds and successfully changes to a different color. There are no errors, drag and drop and what-not all works fine. It looks fine in the editor but not in build.

Comment: Bizarre findings that I don't understand... but the foreach loop was the issue. It must be recognizing cardImages as a length 0 array even though it's not since I am able to remove the for loops and call the images directly with their array value.

Answer (score 0):

Can you turn off the `Recast Target` for `Image`s that are not needed for the decision? I have habitually turned it off since the same symptom occurred on my Android a long time ago. It's well worth a try if the device that is experiencing the symptoms is Android.

[image]

Turn off `Raycast Target` for `Image` not related to touch operation.
[image]

Comment: There are Image components on the parent (Card_16) above, Image, and Frame. I unchecked that box in the prefab on each of them and things still worked fine in the editor. Still no luck in the game build though. There is a Canvas Group on the parent as well, but it doesn't seem to be having any effect either.

Comment: Sorry for not being helpful.

Comment: No worries, it was worth a try.